# App crashes when requesting permission

Tags: android, permissions, crash, android-permissions

I'm using this code to request SMS permission before running the method `SendSMS(string 1, string 2);`
but my app crashes before permission request takes place.
What's missing?

```
 final private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

private void SendCreditSMS() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        SendSMS("181", "رصيد");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put logcat when you have error

Comment: Share log cat of error message

Comment: Where is error log ?

Comment: post your stack trace..error log

Comment: I have the feeling that it fails on pre-Marshmallow devices. Doesn't it?

Comment: Probably you have not declared this permission in your manifest file. Share your logcat trace for more clarity

Comment: add SEND_SMS permission in your manifest file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: -There are no errors during debug. App force closes on phone. Phone is running Android 6.0. And yes, permission is added in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    final private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;


    private void SendCreditSMS() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_CODE);
            } else 
            {
                SendSMS("181", "رصيد");
            }
        }
        else{
            SendSMS("181", "رصيد");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed here?

Comment: you are using Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS .Try to use android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the reason that you declared the activity in which you request permission(s) as with no history. To solve the problem remove 
`android:noHistory="true"`
line from the associated activity's code block in AndroidManifest file. To have an activity with no history you can use other calls such as `finishAndRemoveTask()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the application manager in your android device and select the app you are currently executing. Then check whether permissions are given by the device to use send_sms service in your device.